# A list comprehension of lambdas returns the same values

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, list-comprehension

I've found this example somewhere, and I cannot understand it.

```
>>> mult = [lambda x:x*i for i in range(4)]
>>> mult
[<function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0xb6823464>, <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0xb682341c>, <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0xb68234f4>, <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0xb682353c>]
>>> [m(2) for m in mult]
[6, 6, 6, 6]
>>>
```

As I see, the first line creates a list of lambda functions which I can call afterwards. What I don't understand is the output of `[6,6,6,6]`. As I can see, the elements of `mult` are located in different parts of memory, so, these are not several references to the same data block. But why do they produce the same results? Do all these functions reference the same `i` (which is the last one, which is 3), and why is this happening? And is there a quick way to make such a list of lambdas that would produce `[0,2,4,6]` instead?

Answer (score 3):

`i` is not bound in the body of the `lambda`; its value is looked up once the function is called, so you are creating a list of 4 identical functions. In Python 2, the index of a list comprehension "leaks", since a new scope is not created. When you call each `m`, each sees the same value of `i`, which is the last value `i` was assigned in the comprehension.

The solution is to force `i` to take a specific value in the body of each function. This can be done by using a "do-nothing" parameter, one whose only purpose is to use its default value.

```
mult = [lambda x, i=i:x*i for i in range(4)]
```

Comment: Ah, so in my case I assign a *variable* (not a value) to each function, and in your example I assign a *value* of a (comparatively) "global" `i` to lambda's local `i`?

Comment: More or less.  A better way of looking at it is that in `lambda x: x*i`, `x` is local to the function (via the implicit assignment to a formal parameter), while `i` is a *free* variable. As a free variable, its value is looked up in the closest enclosing scope, in this case the global scope. In `lambda x, i=i: x*i`, now `i` is also a local variable, whose default value is taken from the current value of `i` in the defining scope. (Despite the same name, the first `i` is a formal parameter, the second `i` is a variable in the current scope).

Comment: Yeah, I think it'll take a while for me to understand (and more importantly, bear in mind while programming) free variables. From docs: "If a variable is used in a code block but not defined there, it is a free variable." It was just tricky to notice that the `i` was free.