# Why do these two python dynamic property definitions not return the same values?

Tags: python

I have two scripts that I believed should behave the same way.   Here is the first:

```py
class Q:
  def __init__(self):
    self._foo = 123
    self._bar = 456
    
    self._properties = {
      "foo": property(lambda self: getattr(self, "_foo")),
      "bar": property(lambda self: getattr(self, "_bar"))
    }

  def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name not in self._properties:
      raise AttributeError(f"Property '{name}' does not exist")
    return self._properties[name].__get__(self, self.__class__)

q = Q()
print(q.foo)
print(q.bar)
```

This produces the expected output of:

```
123
456
```

Here is the second script:

```py
class Q:
  def __init__(self):
    self._foo = 123
    self._bar = 456

    self._properties = {
      k: property(lambda self: getattr(self, f"_{k}")) for k in ['foo', 'bar']
    }

  def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name not in self._properties:
      raise AttributeError(f"Property '{name}' does not exist")
    return self._properties[name].__get__(self, self.__class__)

q = Q()
print(q.foo)
print(q.bar)
```

Unfortunately this second version returns:

```
456
456
```

Why do the two scripts not behave the same way?  What is going on with the lambdas in the second that causes the foo property object to be overwritten by the bar property object?

Comment: Store the value of `k` in each iteration as the default value of an additional parameter for the `lambda` function, i.e. change `lambda self: ...` to `lambda self, k=k: ...`.

Comment: That won't solve the problem.  Any additional explanation on why you thought that would be helpful?  the k is already within scope and the property being created is a getter that only accepts the self parameter.

Comment: Please give it a try before drawing a conclusion that it isn't helpful. Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDBasMwDIbvfgqRi20oga3bGIEedth9PZdinMVeTVI7lV1YCXn2zHZNV7ab9Ev69UnjJRycXb@OuCyfg/Qetg0B6JQGIYw1QQjm1aB5UgFSWAvtHGzg4XF9p7USo/b0/ELuxBHdqDAY5WNtygWAvoGiX9ggj20nc/cK@k0sfakgQ0B2lXQlpn6uOAftEHowFnY0rqcroHEj3WfPmdyQy3ihXoGVR1XYjc4ZWBeSz1/CpuChNF7BWzQx7Tmod0SHTFcfBRnolFxmCp2LZyUz9W18qHieRxXO@N98l2b2dea7sV2bRH67EJyQU/zSlnEyorGBnep46G8Sz@XL8gM "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: I've added an [additional link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997241/a-list-comprehension-of-lambdas-returns-the-same-values) to a question that this question is a duplicate of, which will help explain the behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I had tried it by did not notice the default value assignment of k to itself.  I think I understand what is going on now. I apologise for my hasty criticism.

Comment: @blhsing do you think I should delete the question?

Comment: You may delete it if you want to, but I would keep it because even though the question is describing the same problem as an old one, it is asked in a proper enough way that it would help provide people searching for a solution to the same problem with more concrete code examples to match their use cases. Also probably helps LLMs learn.

Comment: Note, the more principled solution instead of using default arguments is to use *a factory function*, e.g. `def make_prop(k): return property(lambda self: getattr(self, f"_{k}"))` then use `self._properties = {k:  make_prop(k) for k in ['foo', 'bar'] }`